# What is the right way of using pragma marks in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've always known that `#pragma mark -` is the way to use pragma marks in Objective-C, but since I started coding in Swift, I accidentally started using `// MARK:` in an Objective-C project. To my surprise, this works as well, and I can see those marks in the menu. Has something in Objectve-C changed? Which way is still preferred? I haven't found any documentation on it.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much down to "whatever your IDE/compiler/code viewer recognizes".

`#pragma` is [just a way for a compiler to provide custom preprocessor facilities](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html). Any given directive can be recognized or not according to the compiler; `#pragma mark -` is not strictly part of ObjC.

The same is true of the comment form, which has been around for quite a while (I can recall using it in Xcode 3, and I'd be surprised if it hadn't been recognized even back in Project Builder). It's just a comment: the question is whether Xcode recognizes the comment as being special.

Answer (score 2):

`// MARK:` is the newer directive and was supported by Xcode 6 beta, back in June 2014.

Both still work, but //, being a comment instead of a preprocessor directive, is a bit more portable.

Comment: It's not new; I can clearly remember using it in Xcode 3, and I'm fairly confident it was recognized before that.